# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider on production ASP.net site, where is it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

On my ASP.net site I have a reference to `Microsoft.SQLserver.SMO`. I copied this reference onto my production server and got a could not load error for `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc`. This error was fixed by copying the dll from the

```
C:\Program files\Microsoft Sql Server\110\SDK\Assembilies
```

However I then got the same error but for `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider` which is nowhere to be found.

Where can I find the `SqlClrProvider` dll? It works on my localhost so it must be somewhere.

Comment: Google for a version appropriate *SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack*, hidden somewhere on the download page will be links to the Shared Management Objects redistributable; install that.

Comment: @AlexK - Do i have to install that on the production server? Because i don't think that is an option. I was hoping to be able to copy all the dlls i needed from my local machine to the web sites bin folder

Comment: Ah, sorry no idea, never tried.

Comment: It's installed in C:\Windows\assembly. You could try copying it from there? As Alex K. mentioned the better solution would be to install the MSI instead. I'm not sure why this isn't included in the SDK\Assemblies folder as part of the installation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server SMO complains of missing DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537613/sql-server-smo-complains-of-missing-dll)

Comment: Oh my, I was unable to access agent jobs through SMO when deployed to IIS. WIth the help of Process Monitor I tracked it down to this dll, ended up here, installed SMO redistributable (and CLR types - a prerequisite), and it finally works. Thanks, Alex K.

Answer (score 22):

On your development machine or a machine where you have SQL Server installed, the `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll` file is in your `GAC`. However, you cannot copy this file without making changes to the registry.

Using the registry editor, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Fusion`. Add a new `DWORD` called `DisableCacheViewer`. Give it a value of `1`.

Once this change is made, you can go to `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider\` to get the dll you need.

To see a more detailed explanation, follow one of these links:

- [HOW TO RESOLVE “SQLCLRPROVIDER NOT FOUND” WITHOUT INSTALLING SQL SERVER ON THE CLIENT MACHINE OR NEEDING A DEPLOYMENT PROJECT](http://blog.waseem-sabjee.com/2013/07/10/how-to-resolve-sqlclrprovider-not-found-without-installing-sql-server-on-the-client-machine-or-needing-a-deployment-project/)
- [Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider](http://big.info/2011/12/could-not-load-file-or-assembly.html)

Comment: Is this still the best way in 2019?

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to make an embedded script in powershell and stumble upon your same problem.

The thing is that `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll` is not installed in SQL files but in windows `assembly`.

`Assembly` folder is special: you can't copy anything with windows UI.

I just needed the `Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll` so that I can load it in my script like that:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($scriptPath+"dll\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll") | out-null
```

to copy it you can do the following:

```
c:\>cd c:\Windows\assembly
c:\Windows\assembly>dir /s Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll
# here you get the directory and the file
c:\Windows\assembly>copy c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider\<version>\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\
```

you want to do that on a machine with SQLserver installed otherwise you may not find it.

It's just a workaround. I guess it's not the best thing to do if you need to execute your script in different environments.

hth

Comment: I've been able to locate, copy and add the missing DLL as a reference in my project, and it does not complain about it missing anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue but for version 11. To get the right assemblies installed a did the following steps:

- Check what version is expected: https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/. Version 11 => sql server 2012
- Download Microsoft's [web platform installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) and install it
- Search for 'sql server 2012' and install one or all of the following:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. I'm working on a .NET project that is from 2012 but I'm using VS2017 on a Win10 machine. Turns out I was missing this Extension.

Answer (score 5):

Copying SqlClrProvider dll into sqlserver Binn directory **didn't** help in my case.

**Cause:**

It was cause by using **different versions** of SQLServer on production machine and target machine.

**Solution:**

Make sure you are using the same version of SMO libraries as you have on the target machines. If there is SQLServer2008 on the target machine you must use v10 libraries otherwise you would get this error.

**MoreDetails:**

SqlServer on my target machines was version 2008 (10) and I had SqlServer2014 (12) on my own machine. When I used SMO library visualstudio added v12 libraries (**Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO, ...**) but smo is just a shell which use SqlClrProvider and it expects to have SqlClrProvider of same version on system assemblies. this caused the application to crash on the target machine since the v12 of SqlClrProvider didn't exist. By using v10 smo libraries I solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you need to do is disable the GAC Shell extension which allows you to browse the GAC, to do this:

- Open “regedit”
- Navigate to
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Fusion
- Add a new DWORD or 32
  bit DWORD named DisableCacheViewer with the Hex value of 0x1 or a
  decimal value of 1

That disables the GAC Shell allowing you to fully browse assembly folder, now we can extract the assembly from the GAC and drop it into the bin folder or the dll location on the client machine.

- Go to C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider\
- You may notice more than folder here, this is for each version of SQL server you have installed
- For SQL 2012 it will be : \11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91
- You will then find the file Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll

[Reference](http://blog.waseem-sabjee.com/2013/07/10/how-to-resolve-sqlclrprovider-not-found-without-installing-sql-server-on-the-client-machine-or-needing-a-deployment-project/)

Answer (score 2):

I could not solve my issue, while using `Microsoft.Sqlerver.SMO` reference. So I instead used the `System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator` class for all my Sql functionality needs.

Answer (score 1):

For people googling this error, and arriving here, there is another possibility.  Go into Services, and make sure that your SQL Server process can run.  On my machine, the password for the user account had changed.  Once I fixed the password, the process started, and I no longer received the above error.